# Missleading ADF Results

Tags: stationarity, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

I am trying to use the adfuller test to determine whether the following timeseries is mean reverting (stationary)
[image: timeseries chart]

From the chart we can see that its obviously (at least my non-expert eye) non stationary, not even trend stationary. However, here are the results of the adfuller test:

`adfuller(x=series, regression='c', autolag='AIC')`

```
(-2.861823362791237,
 0.049970939795951415,
 0,
 123,
 {'1%': -3.4846672514209773,
  '5%': -2.8853397507076006,
  '10%': -2.5794629869786503},
 474.99227678339616)
```

One observation I made is that its running the adf test with 0 lags. So I assume its basically running the plain Dickey-Fuller test, not its augmented version. Anyways, I have no idea how Dickey-Fuller test can conclude that this is a stationary series.

Here are also the results of the underlying regression:

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qK38.png): [image: OLS results]

Could someone please explain how this is possible?

By the way, if I slice the timeseries to include everything only up to index 80, the results of the adfuller are the following:

```
(-1.3640306149972252,
 0.5993937238755126,
 0,
 83,
 {'1%': -3.5117123057187376,
  '5%': -2.8970475206326833,
  '10%': -2.5857126912469153},
 292.00388101290173)
```

So it seems that the points following index 80 are the ones that mess up the adf test by making the test statistic low enough for it to be significant. Am I right that this is the cause of the problem? If yes, is there a better test for mean reversion that would conclude that series like in my question are not mean reverting?

Last thing, as a workaround I decided to smooth the series using Savitzky–Golay filter. It seems to be doing a good job, but I am not sure if that is the way to go. Any advise on that?

Comment: The ADF test assesses the null hypothesis that the series has a unit root. Yours does not seem to have one, so the ADF test rejects $H_0$. No surprises there. Regarding the filter, what is the purpose of your analysis? Depending on that, a filter may or may not be useful.

Comment: @RichardHardy thank you for your reply! Can you please explain why you think this series has a unit root? The main purpose of my analysis is finding mean reverting series form a universe of timeseries (stationary, not trend-stationary). I would very appreciate if you could suggest a better way of doing so.

Comment: Read my comment again to see I wrote the opposite of what you suggest.

Comment: @RichardHardy Yeah, I mean does not have a unit root, sorry for the confusion. Could you please explain why thats the case? And given my goal of finding mean reverting pairs, could you suggest a better solution?

Comment: I have seen quite a few time series in career, and this one does not look like the ones that contain unit roots. Thus, it is no more than an eye test. Of course, I could be wrong. I do not have a suggestion for finding mean-reverting series, sorry.